# Update an existing Kubernetes golang Operator

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I have a Kubernetes go lang operator docker image created by an older version of operator-sdk. Need to add customizations on top of it on the controller.go file. Would like to know a way to update this operator image with the customizations and create a new operator image.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The best way right now is to scaffold out a new operator and copy over any customizations.